# How to use environment variables for GET method in POSTMAN Tool?

Tags: postman, environment

how can I use environment variables for get method in postman, I have customer id's with me but I need to send different customer id's n check the response, but I want to send customer ID's through data driven in postman tool

Answer (score 0):

Imagine there is a `customerId` in env variables. To send this value in body or as param, just replace the static value with `{{customerId}}`.
[image]

usage:
[image]

To update the variable, imagine we have the following response:

```json
{
 "success": true,
 "data": {
   "id": "1234"
 }
}
```

in the test tab update it this way:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if(data && data.data && data.data.id){
  pm.environment.set('customerId', data.data.id)
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is for post method, but for examples for GET method my URI is https://example.com/custinfo/23456789 where 23456789 i the customer id, so I want to send multiple  id's using a variable, for suppose the URI is https://example.com/custinfo/{{x}}, where x is an environment variable, i want to pass multiple customer id's from .csv file, how to do this????

Comment: Have you read any of the Postman documentation?

Comment: yes I haven't seen any document of GET method using environment variable

Comment: Any other answers

Comment: did you try adding this postman.setEnvironmentVariable('tutorial','postman') , more info here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/creating-variables-using-pre-request-script-using-postman